# Updating PyQt5 QTextBrowser inside running function

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing

I’ve been trying to make a log of some lengthy file transfer and copy tasks along with a progress bar so that the end user has some idea of how far along the process they are. I have tried using multiprocessing but as I am trying to pass in ‘self’ from a class into a function it is unable to pickle. I have attached a snippet of my code below. The function it calls (fileCopy) is all working and has ‘self.log.setText()’ in it to update the log. Is there anyway I can have a live log and progress bar working while the function is running?

Thank you in advance

```
    class Processing(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Processing, self).__init__()
            loadUi("UIFiles/processing.ui", self)
            self.options = self.getOptions()
            self.next.hide()
            self.pause.clicked.connect(self.pauseClicked)
            fileCopy(self, options)
```

Comment: Use [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) to do the file-io and send progress updates to the ui via custom signals. There are many examples on SO and elsewhere that show how to do this.